# Why does Scapy's pkt.haslayer(Dot11) seem to work for everyone else in the world but me?

Tags: python, scapy

I've been writing little scripts and experimenting with Scapy.

I've followed many tutorials and MOST say to define your packet handler with `pkt` as input and then immediately an `if` statement that checks if the packet is `Dot11`.

This has NEVER worked for me as I get nothing.

#### Example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11   # \
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff       #  > Tried all of these without success.
from scapy.all import *                # /

def packetHandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        print("yay!")

sniff(iface="wlan0", prn=packetHandler)
```

I'm using Arch Linux and Python3. I've also tried this in Python2 with no success.

And YES my card is in monitor mode and is `up`.

I've successfully made many scripts using Scapy, but NONE with this `if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):` statement.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: What version are you using? You should retry using the github dev version

Comment: I'm using Scapy version 2.4.3-2

Comment: Retry using the github dev version should help

Comment: I truly appreciate the advice but it doesn't answer my question. Also, I should have clarified that this problem has been the case for me for years across many (complete OS) installs. Perhaps I should do as you suggest as a troubleshooting tool and not as a solution to see if it will work but I'd really like to find the root cause as it SHOULD work the way it's installed now. Also I should include that everything else Scapy seems to work fine.

Comment: Anyone? This seems so elementary I can't believe it's unanswered.

Comment: do you see anything if you remove the if ? (but for real don't ask for help if it's so "elementary")

Comment: Woa man, I mean no offense. What I mean by "elementary" is that it seems like I'm missing something super obvious that everyone else in the world understands but me. What alternative way would you suggest? Or, better yet, I'd like to know if anyone else has experienced this (Goolge found nothing). I've been beating myself up over this one for a long time.

Comment: There's a comment in [this issue](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1854#issuecomment-570034404) that suggests that `haslayer` is broken for Dot11, they suggest just trying to access it and catching the exception as a work around